# вопрос по fetchmode jpa + hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Вот на просторах инета нарыл следующее что дефолтные значения данного атрибута являются следующими

```
From the JPA 2.0 spec, the defaults are like so:
OneToMany: LAZY
ManyToOne: EAGER
ManyToMany: LAZY
OneToOne: EAGER
And in hibernate, all is Lazy
```

То есть справедливо предположить что при связке jpa + hibernate будут браться настройки именно хибера? Он же является реализацией Jpa, а значит настройки jpa проигнорируются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA - это спецификация. Нет настроек конкретно JPA, нет связок. JPA - человек, Hibernate - Вася. У людей две руки, две ноги. Справедливо ли при связке человек + Вася будут браться настройки именно Васи? Раз Hibernate - это спецификация JPA, а в JPA заданы такие значения по умолчанию, то в Hibernate будут такие значения по умолчанию.

Comment: Ну значит я прав, благодарю.